# Node does not run Jest tests written in typescript correctly

Tags: node.js, jestjs, ts-jest

I have an Angular 15 application with some Jest tests written in TypeScript. Here's an example of such a test:

```js
//my-test.spec.ts
import Mocked = jest.Mocked

describe('SomeTest', () => {
    let mock:Mocked<any>

    beforeEach(() => {
        // some setup logic
    })

    it('should ...', () => {
        // some testing logic
    })

})
```

I have installed `jest`, `@types/jest`, `ts-jest` and `jest-preset-angular` as dev-dependencies, so they're in my package.json. I have also created a default config file for `jest-ts` [as documented](https://kulshekhar.github.io/ts-jest/docs/getting-started/installation/#creating) using `npx ts-jest config:init` and configured it to use the `jest-preset-angular` configuration. Here is the content of the relevant files:

```js
// jest.config.js
module.exports = {
    preset: 'jest-preset-angular',
    setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/setup-jest.ts'],
    globalSetup: 'jest-preset-angular/global-setup',
};
```

```js
// setup-jest.ts
import 'jest-preset-angular/setup-jest'
```

The tests run just fine when running with the globally installed npm package: `jest --watch`. I wanted to add this command to `package.json` under `scripts` as follows:

```json
{
...
    "scripts": {
        ...
        "test": "jest --detectOpenHandles",
        "test:watch": "jest --watch",
        ...
    },
...
}
```

However, when running the tests with `npm test` from the command line, the run fails:

```bash
  ● Test suite failed to run

    SyntaxError: /my-test.spec.ts: Unexpected token, expected "from" (6:14)
```

Looks like Jest is not using the `ts-jest`-precompiler when running tests with `npm` and treating `my-test.spec.ts` like a JavaScript file. What's wrong here?